# moment js date library, formatting on IE gives a NaN

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

im using moment js date library to format a date, but on IE
i get a NaN on the output. It works fine on other browsers, like Chrome, FF, etc.

```
var value = "2015-11";

moment(value).format("YYYY-DD-01 00:00")    
> "0NaN-NaN-01 00:00"
```

I was able to fix it by adding the same pattern on moment constructor like below:

```
> moment(value,"YYYY-DD-01 00:00").format("YYYY-DD-01 00:00")   
"2015-11-01 00:00"
```

Is it a good practice to add this pattern on the constructor, for all moment objects creation
so it can work also on IE?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The input format should match what you are providing:

```
var value = "2015-11";
moment(value, "YYYY-MM")
```

If you want to format it differently for *output*, that's when you use the `.format` method.

```
var value = "2015-11";
var m = moment(value, "YYYY-MM")
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM")
```

Note that you were specifying `DD` which is the day formatter.  But based on the usage, I think you meant `MM` for month.

Comment: Very good answer, thanks for solution.
Can you tell why its happening only in IE

Comment: Nonstandard parsing without supplying an input format falls back to the browser, which is implementation specific and varies across browsers, which is why you should always provide an input format.